# How to INNER JOIN with SUM

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to join two tables, one with sales and one with profile. both table has same customer No but sales table didn't have customer name. How do I inner join them so that I can get top 10 highest sum amount sales of  customers, but I want to show their name instead.
I've tried to use query below:

```
SELECT TOP 10 b.Amount, a.CustomerName  
FROM       SalesDetail b 
INNER JOIN CustomerProfile a 
        ON a.CustomerNo = b.CustomerNo 
ORDER BY Amount DESC
```

and it shows repeated customer name, and amount is not summed up. trying to group the customer will prompt an error

```
SELECT TOP 10 b.Amount, a.CustomerName  
FROM       SalesDetail b 
INNER JOIN CustomerProfile a 
        ON a.CustomerNo = b.CustomerNo 
GROUP BY a.CustomerName 
ORDER BY b.Amount DESC
```

without inner join, this is where I've made so far. I can sum it up but I'll only get customer No and sales amount.

```
SELECT  TOP 10 CustomerNo, SUM (Amount) AS 'Total' 
FROM     SalesDetail 
GROUP BY CustomerNo
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Tip: Get into the habit of using at least faintly meaningful aliases, e.g. `SalesDetail as SD` and `CustomerProfile as CP`. It makes life easier than `b` and `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to join two tables, one with sales and one with profile.
>   both table has same customer No

Just use `INNER JOIN` with `ON` `CustomerNo`

```
FROM       SalesDetail s
INNER JOIN CustomerProfile c
        ON s.CustomerNo = c.CustomerNo
```

> so that I can get top 10 highest sum amount sales of customers

You will need to use `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` together with `TOP`

```
SELECT   TOP (10) c.CustomerName, SUM (Amount) AS Total
FROM       SalesDetail s
INNER JOIN CustomerProfile c
        ON s.CustomerNo = c.CustomerNo 
GROUP BY c.CustomerName  
ORDER BY SUM (Amount) DESC
```

Comment: It seems like i left out to include SUM in the ORDER BY. Thank you very much for your help.